Question about orthogonal eigenvectors
I know that given a normal matrix A, then distinct eigenvalues correspond to orthogonal eigenvectors. I've seen the proof by contradiction which only relies on the definition of the inner product. what I don't get is how the orthogonality of the eigenvectors is true without having to define the inner product explicitly.
take for example the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times3}$ with some inner product $\langle , \rangle$, and the matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(EDIT:
Given a vector $v \,\epsilon \, \mathbb{R}^{3}$ this matrix defines the operator:
$$T:\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} \,\,\,\,\, T(v)=Av$$
$A$ is symmetric and therefore normal, so its distinct eigenvectors should be orthogonal)
$A$ has eigenvalues 4, 2, 1 with eigenvectors $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, ( Standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$), which means that the standard basis vectors are orthogonal w.r.t the inner product. Does this mean that the standard basis vectors are orthogonal w.r.t any inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times3}$ ? This doesn't make sense to me since one would expect that the orthogonality of vectors should depend on the inner product. By this line of thinking I could define a symmetric matrix to have whatever distinct eigenvectors I want and they would be orthogonal w.r.t any inner product.
I feel like I am missing something about the definition of the inner product or what makes vectors orthogonal. Any clarification on the subject would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Of course orthogonality depends on the inner product. It defines what is meant by orthogonality.

Definition of normality depends on the inner product. An operator $A$ is normal if $AA^* = A^*A$, and the adjoint $A^*$ is defined using the equality $\left<A^*x, y\right> = \left<x, Ay\right>$. This is where the inner product comes in.
So regarding your example: of course there are inner products with respect to which the stardard basis is not orthogonal. But with respect to these inner products the operator defined by the diagonal matrix will also not be normal.

I guess my confusion lay in the definition of the adjoint. from what I understood, in addition to the definition you gave, over the complex/reals the representing matrix of the adjoint operator is the conjugate transpose, or is that just a special case that narrows down the type of inner product?

The adjoint linear map is represented by the conjugate transpose matrix only in an orthonormal basis.
